# Should i change the URL in android when changing the localhost port to 7080?

Tags: android, apache, port

when running this code on port 80 it

String regurl ="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";

String loginurl ="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";

BUT when i changed the port number in the httpd.conf
from 80 to 7080 
the application stopped..
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Change your url to

String regurl ="http://10.0.2.2:7080/webapp/register.php";

String loginurl ="http://10.0.2.2:7080/webapp/login.php";

**Explanation**

Port number 80 is the default port for http and https connections. When you run your webserver's that accepts a http or httpsconnections they will listen at this port to receive the connection from client :)

Webservers running with special privilages are allowed to access port number 80 for ex: apache runs at port number 80 where as servlet containers like tomcat dont have permission to run at port 80 they run at 8080 :)

You can use few commands and make them to listen to port 80 or you can have a apache as reverse proxy and make those servers which dont have permission to listen to port 80 to make them behave as if they are listening to port 80 :)

When you type a url like http://google.com request goes to the server having an ip which is mapped to domain name google.com and upon reaching the server which port to handover the request to ??? it hands it over to default port 80 :)

But if you want to redirect your request to specific port instead you can append :portnumber to the end of your url :)
like http://google.com:7080

**Conclusion**
http://google.com = http://google.com:80 will reach port 80
http://google.com:7080 will reach port 7080 :)

Hope I made my point clear :)